# group by clause is not producing the expected sum

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, group-by, sum

I am developing iPhone applications and using sqlite database.

I am having answers_ELA table as follows:

```
Id    | observation_id    | question_no    | answer    | answer2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 60                | 0              | 2         | 1
2     | 60                | 1              | 3         | 4
3     | 61                | 0              | 3         | 4
4     | 61                | 1              | 3         | 2
5     | 62                | 0              | 3         | 1
6     | 62                | 1              | 1         | 2
```

And I want result

```
question_no    | total
-------------------------
0              | 14
1              | 15
```

But its giving

```
question_no    | total
-------------------------
0              | 4
1              | 3
```

Means for last observation_id only i.e. 62

And the query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    question_no,
    (answer+answer2) total
FROM 
    answers_ELA 
WHERE
    observation_id IN(60,61,62) 
GROUP BY 
    question_no
```

What's wrong in this, and what should I do to get desired3 result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT question_no, SUM(answer+answer2) total
FROM answers_ELA 
WHERE observation_id IN (60,61,62) 
GROUP BY question_no
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no aggregation function assigned. Try SUM(answer+answer2).

Answer (score 0):

Guess, this one will work for you...

```
SELECT question_no, 
       Sum(answer + answer2) total 
FROM   answers_ela 
WHERE  observation_id IN( 60, 61, 62 ) 
GROUP  BY question_no
ORDER  BY question_no;
```